# How to update Google Play Services on an Android Virtual Device?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-virtual-device

I am trying to test my app on older versions of Android, so I decided to create a Google Nexus AVD running on API 16 with Google APIs. But first, I made sure I downloaded the Google APIs from the Android SDK Manager for Android 4.2.1 (API 16).

When running my app, I always get the following message :

```
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9683000 but found 9256030
```

So how can I update the Google Play services if I already got the latest version of Google APIs?

Comment: AFAIK, for instance, Android 4.1 (with Google APIs) means this image has **standalone** Google API. A specific version is shipped with this image.

Comment: But this is stupid, people with Android 4.1 can still update their Google Play services... How can I test my app on older devices without having to own them physically?

Comment: What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: I haven't found any. If I want to test on older Android versions, I must find real old devices...